# ARM template doesnt pick up defaultvalues

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Trying to use my first ARM custom deployment template.
Deployment works - but the template refuses to pick up default values when I hit 'deploy' - which means they have to type every time...very frustrating. what am I doing wrong?

Here's the ARM code:

```
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultvalue": "australiaeast"
    },
    "resourceGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultvalue": "Veeam-Backup"
    }
```

So you can see that both Location and Resource Group have default values.
But when I press 'deploy', this is what pops up:

[image: screen shot of deployment window]

Both values under SETTINGS are blank.
What have I missed?

Comment: hello @ScubaAl, can you please try using "defaultValue": with V in caps or just "value": .

Answer (score 0):

I have done the deployment through the azure portal by giving the default parameters in the arm template by using
**defaultValue** instead of **defaultvalue** and it worked.

Refer this screenshot below:

[image]